# не меняется значение в $scope при использовании функции

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пробую менять значение в скоупе через `ng-click`, `ng-click='currentTab = 1'` или `ng-click='currentTab = 2'`, это "Обычн" кнопки, таким образом `$scope.currentTab` будет менять свое значение. Есть также 3я "Функц" кнопка которая также меняет значение currentTab, но уже с помощью функции в контроллере. И когда я нажимаю на "Функц" - присваиваеться корректный номер, по клику на "Обычн" - меняеться, но вот после "Обычн" кнопки "Функц" кнопка уже не работает. Функция в контроллере на кнопку "Функц" простая:

```
$scope.change = function() {
    $rootScope.currentTab = 1;
  }
```

В данном случае инетересно почему именно с рутСкоуп оно не хочет менять обратно, ведь в целом разницы не должно быть никакой..
  пример планкр:
https://plnkr.co/edit/yntkXTRS7YC0EgfSNr9k?p=preview

upd: с $scope оно будет работать корректно, но вот именно с $rootScope интересно в чем дело..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит из-за наследования скопов.

`$rootScope` - скоп верхнего уровня, его поля/свойства/методы доступны во всех скопах.

При использовании директивы `ng-controller` - для нее создается свой собственный скоп, наследуемый от `$rootScope`.

весь вывод во view делается в контексте скопа контроллера.

#### Почему это работает первый раз?

При отсутствии поля в объекте, это поле ищется в прототипе объекта. В данном случае, после нажатия кнопки с функцией - свойство добавляется в `$rootScope`, который является прототипом текущего скоп, и так как в текущем скопе нет данного свойства, показывается значение установленное в `$rootScope`.

#### Почему не работает после нажатия кнопок?

При нажатии остальных кнопок - поле добавляется **непосредственно** в текущий скоп.

И значение берется напрямую из него.

Comment: понял, доходчиво и ясно) спасибо!